# React Hooks with Styled Components - Form not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, styled-components

So I'm using React Hooks with styled components, I have tried to style a form but when I make it into a styled component the form doesn't work ie you type one letter then the form looses focus, you have to click back into the input box, type one letter and it looses focus again etc...

I'm also getting this warning in the dev tools but I don't really understand what I need to do -

index.js:27 The component styled.form with the id of "sc-eCssSg" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.
at LocationForm (https://3deis.csb.app/src/Components/LocationForm.js:31:39)
at div
at App (https://3deis.csb.app/src/App.js:53:39)

How do I change the below code to do what is needed to make it work ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";

const LocationForm = (props) => {
  const [locationName, setName] = useState("");

  const Form = styled.form``;

  const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    axios
      .get(
        `http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=z2G40AM2VSDfXx7MQtCqAvmXmoYEX8cV&location=${locationName}&maxResults=1`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const latitude = res.data.results[0].locations[0].displayLatLng.lat;
        const longitude = res.data.results[0].locations[0].displayLatLng.lng;
        const city = res.data.results[0].locations[0].adminArea5;
        // const submitted = !true;

        props.callbackFromParent(
          locationName,
          // submitted,
          latitude,
          longitude,
          city
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Location:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={locationName}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default LocationForm;
```

Comment: "To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component"

Answer (score 2):

It says exactly what is happening. You are creating `const Form = styled.form` inside your `LocationForm` render function. If you move it 4 lines up outsie the function it will stop giving the warning. In general you should never create a styled component inside a render function, because it will recreate the form each render (so each time you input a character) instead of only once upon initialization.

Comment: oh! I see what you mean, thanks so much for explaining that!

Comment: Glad it helped. Would you mind accepting the answer if it helped your case?